# Why is PHP moving everything from the <head> tag to the <body> tag?

Tags: php, html

I honestly don't know how to explain this, the best I can do is show examples.

1: [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUEve.png) - [DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUvYG.png)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="main">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good! Everything's working perfectly in #1. However, when I add PHP to the code...

2: [HTML/PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8u4D.png) - [DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPMth.png)

```
<?php
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/classes/main.php");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="main">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, including that file moved everything in the `<head>` tag into `<body>`. Also, there's two new lines in `<body>` that's putting an annoying space between the top of the window and the content.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you include the code here?

Comment: You should include your `main.php` inside your `<body>` tag

Comment: What is in `main.php`??

Comment: @codyogden It uses spl_autoload_register to include files if I try to use them. For example, if I used `new Status()`, it would include `/classes/Status.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was because of the include_once() or include().

When you save a page as UTF-8, a special signature called a byte-order mark (or BOM) is included at the beginning of the file, indicating that it is a UTF-8 file. You can only see BOMs with low level text editors (such as DOS edit). You need to remove this signature from the included file in order to get rid of the white space at the top of the page.

You can solve this problem doing the following:

```
$file = file_get_contents('header.php');
$file = substr($file, 3, strlen($file));
echo $file;
```

By doing this you avoid character.

OR

In Notepad++ you can change the encoding of the file to "UTF-8 without BOM" from the "Encoding" menu.

Comment: Thanks! I have had BOM problems with the same file before, but I never thought that the BOM might be causing that, too.